# Elementor shows Chinese characters on Menu

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have just installed Elementor on a Wordpress site but the design tools menu on the page editor contain Chinese symbols instead of the usual symbols. I have deleted the Elementor plugin and copied the folder from another Wordpress site which works OK, but this copy also shows the symbols in the new site.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a third-party conflict. Try deactivating your third-party plugins and then check by activating one plugin at a time. If this solve your issue. And, check your site language as well. If still it does not resolve the issue, I would advice to connect with Elementor Support Team

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have de-activated all the other plugins and it is still the same, the language is English (UK). This is very strange, this test site and the live site are both domains on the same server. I will contact Elementor